# Share data between users in a MEAN app

Tags: mean, data-sharing

I am creating a MEAN app with flashcards and I want to implement sharing functionality: User A can share one or more flashcards set, and user B can add them to his own sets and learn.

How can this be achieved, is there some library for this? What would be the steps to add the functionality to the app?

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you have a place to store flashcard sets? Does sharing mean that User B can edit the cards or just train with them? Are the cards otherwise private to the creating user unless shared? You do not need a library to achieve this: it's just a matter of defining the above constraints and implementing them with access control and some way of tracking a user's use of a given set: e.g., User B + Shared Card Set + Current Learning Score.

Comment: So far I have the angular app on express server and the API to work with the database. I store the flashcards sets in mongodb. User B can not edit the shared flashcards, just train with them. Or he can add the shared set to his own collection and then edit + train.The cards are private to the creating user unless shared.

Comment: It sounds like you've got everything you need implemented then to make this happen. Just a matter of hooking it up. Put some sort of flag on a deck with allowed users, defaulting to the deck owner. Sharing just means the owner adds X user to the "allowed users" list. Listing the decks User B can see is just filtering out the decks by allowed_users.contains(User B.id) and displaying them. If you have tons of decks, you could maintain a list of "my decks" tied to each user with allowed IDs (those they have created, and those that have been shared with them).

Comment: Now I've understood what to do, thanks a lot!